# Color axis text by variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to vary the color of my heatmap axis text depending on another variable in the dataset.  This is what I've tried so far:

```
#load data, scale numeric columns, add state abbreviation and region
state_data <- data.frame(state.x77)
state_data <- state_data[,1:8]
state_data <- rescaler(state_data, type='range')
state_data$State <- state.abb
state_data$Region <- state.region

#make heatmap
melted_state <- melt(state_data,id.vars=c('State', 'Region'))

p <- ggplot(melted_state, 
        aes(x=State, y=variable))
p <- p + geom_tile(aes(fill = value), colour = "white")
p <- p + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(colour="Region")) ## doesn't work!
p
```

I get this error:
Error in grid.Call(L_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : 
  invalid color name 'Region'

And if I remove the quotes around 'Region' I get this error:

> ```
> Error in structure(list(family = family, face = face, colour = colour,  : 
>   object 'Region' not found
> ```

How can I do this?

Comment: interesting, but I think this is an axis of flexibility not considered by the `ggplot2` author(s), so it may be hard to do.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Settings accessed via `theme` cannot be mapped to the data like aesthetics unfortunately. You will need to construct an appropriate palette (read: list) of colors manually.

One way to do so would be something like this:

```
library(scales)
numColors <- length(levels(melted_state$Region)) # How many colors you need
getColors <- scales::brewer_pal('qual') # Create a function that takes a number and returns a qualitative palette of that length (from the scales package)
myPalette <- getColors(numColors)
names(myPalette) <- levels(state_data$Region) # Give every color an appropriate name
p <- p + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour=myPalette[state_data$Region])))
```

Comment: Any suggestions for how to work this when the order of the labels does not match the order of the factor (for example when labels are reordered in ggplot or when using facets).  Is there a way to extract the order of labels from the ggplot object?

Comment: I always set the order of the variables with a factor. If you do this before hand you should be good. you can extract `breaks` info from a ggplot object but its kinda of a pain...

Comment: With the last version of `ggplot` (`ggplot2_3.4.0`) it's not already possible: ``Vectorized input to `element_text()` is not officially supported.``